# Offline MDM profile switching iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, device, enterprise, mdm

Is it possible to have MDM profiles stored locally on a device and then switched dynamically? Preferably by an API so an App could do this. With an MDM such as [Absolute Manage MDM](http://www.absolute.com/en/products/absolute-manage/mdm) and [Meraki](https://meraki.cisco.com/products/systems-manager) they say this can not be done.

I understand that any App is sandboxed and I myself feel like this is not possible but I need some answers to tell management rather than me just saying no.

Jailbreaking is an option but only if there is no other way.

Any help would be great. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After further research this was not possible with iOS. I called several MDM providers and spoke to qualified engineers that confirm it not possible without internet connectivity.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this, if your have local MDM server (meaning running on a device itself). This way you can switch profiles locally.

There is no public API to manipulate profiles for iOS. And as I remember private API's which are designed to do that are protected by entitlements. So, signing an app with enterprise cert isn't an option.

Jailbreak is an option.

P.S. I have no idea how Absolute Manage MDM and Meraki does what they claim to do.

Comment: Are you aware of any MDMS that can be ran on an iOS device? I did some searching and came up with nothing.

Comment: This is not a standard thing. All MDM providers wants to manage whole fleet of devices, so it makes only sense to have it on the server side. If you decide to go this route, most likely you will have to implement your own solution.